# SSIS and Excel import

Tags: sql-server, ssis, excel, ssis-2012

I am using VS2012 and creating a package on a 64bit machine to import some data from a `.xlsx` file.  My question is that I am getting an error for the Excel connection manager, do I need to install some kind of excel driver or excel itself on the machine in order to be able to import the data?

The error is

> Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager
> 'Excel Connection Manager'.  Failed to connect to the source using the
> connection manager.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to configure SSIS to run in 32-bit runtime as Excel does not support 64-bit

Go to the Property page for the Solution, select Debugging and change **Run64BitRuntime** to False

[Running 32-bit SSIS in a 64-bit Environment](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2010/03/24/running-32-bit-ssis-in-a-64-bit-environment.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have actually fixed this now by installing the 32-bit ACE OLE DB provider

Thanks